# Learning Haskell and found an error in some sample code

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-stack

When I learn a new language, the first thing I do is to read through a Fast Fourier Transform implementation and try to get it to work. It's an algorithm that I'm fairly familiar with - so it helps me to understand how the language works.

Currently, I'm reading through [this](https://ro-che.info/articles/2015-12-04-fft) implementation by Roman Cheplyaka. I have followed the algorithm very closely now and everything seems to work as intended, but the following piece of code throws a bunch of errors for me: (specifically, the `squareMap` part throws the error)

```
evalFourier coeffs pts = do
  let
    squares = nub $ u_sqr <$> pts -- values of x^2
    (even_coeffs, odd_coeffs) = split coeffs
  even_values <- evalFourier even_coeffs squares
  odd_values <- evalFourier odd_coeffs squares

  let
    -- a mapping from x^2 to (A_e(x^2), A_o(x^2))
    square_map =
      Map.fromList
      . zip squares
      $ zip even_values odd_values

    -- evaluate the polynomial at a single point
    eval1 :: U -> Writer (Sum Int) (Complex a)
    eval1 x = do
      let (ye,yo) = (square_map Map.! u_sqr x)
          r = ye + toComplex x * yo
      tell $ Sum 2 -- this took two arithmetic operations
      return r

  mapM eval1 pts
```

Note that `Map` is short for `Data.Map` and here are some non-standard library functions that were defined in the implementation:

```
-- | U q corresponds to the complex number exp(2 i pi q)
newtype U = U Rational
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

-- | Convert a U number to the equivalent complex number
toComplex :: Floating a => U -> Complex a
toComplex (U q) = mkPolar 1 (2 * pi * realToFrac q)

-- | Smart constructor for U numbers; automatically performs normalization
mkU :: Rational -> U
mkU q = U (q - realToFrac (floor q))

-- | Raise a U number to a power
uPow :: U -> Integer -> U
uPow (U q) p = mkU (fromIntegral p*q)

-- | Square a U number
uSqr :: U -> U
uSqr x = uPow x 2
```

Here is the error that shows after I run `stack build`:

```
src\FFT.hs:43:13: error:
    * Couldn't match type `a' with `a1'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          evalFourier :: forall a.
                         RealFloat a =>
                         [Complex a] -> [U] -> Writer (Sum Int) [Complex a]
        at src\FFT.hs:(19,1)-(22,35)
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          eval1 :: forall a1. U -> Writer (Sum Int) (Complex a1)
        at src\FFT.hs:38:9-50
      Expected type: WriterT
                       (Sum Int) Data.Functor.Identity.Identity (Complex a1)
        Actual type: WriterT
                       (Sum Int) Data.Functor.Identity.Identity (Complex a)
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: return r
      In the expression:
        do let (ye, yo) = (squareMap Map.! uSqr x)
               r = ye + toComplex x * yo
           tell $ Sum 2
           return r
      In an equation for `eval1':
          eval1 x
            = do let (ye, yo) = ...
                     ....
                 tell $ Sum 2
                 return r
    * Relevant bindings include
        r :: Complex a (bound at src\FFT.hs:41:17)
        ye :: Complex a (bound at src\FFT.hs:40:18)
        yo :: Complex a (bound at src\FFT.hs:40:21)
        eval1 :: U -> Writer (Sum Int) (Complex a1)
          (bound at src\FFT.hs:39:9)
        squareMap :: Map.Map U (Complex a, Complex a)
          (bound at src\FFT.hs:33:9)
        oddValues :: [Complex a] (bound at src\FFT.hs:30:5)
        (Some bindings suppressed; use -fmax-relevant-binds=N or -fno-max-relevant-binds)
   |
43 |             return r
   |             ^^^^^^^^


--  While building custom Setup.hs for package FastFourier-0.1.0.0 using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\5c8418a7 build lib:FastFourier exe:FastFourier-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Can anyone please point out what is causing the error I'm seeing here? I have a feeling this error has something to do with the line `let (ye,yo) = (square_map Map.! u_sqr x)`. Thanks.

Comment: Should note that numeric code probably isn't the easiest way to get used to Haskell as most popular algorithm rely on mutable buffers - which you can get in Haskell, but they're not a first class feature.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're missing two pieces from the linked code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

at the top and

```
evalFourier
  :: forall a . RealFloat a
  => [Complex a] -- ^ polynomial coefficients, starting from a_0
  -> [U] -- ^ points at which to evaluate the polynomial
  -> Writer (Sum Int) [Complex a]
```

as the type signature for `evalFourier`.

Without `ScopedTypeVariables`, the two `a` type variables (in the type of `evalFourier` and the nested `eval1 :: U -> Writer (Sum Int) (Complex a)`) are independent. In particular, the type of `eval1` specifies a fully general result type, which is not matched by the function body.

With `ScopedTypeVariables`, the inner `a` in the type of `eval1` refers to the outer `a` defined by `forall a. ...`.

The `{-# LANGUAGE ... #-}` construct is a [pragma](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pragmas) (a compiler directive).

The [`LANGUAGE` pragma](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#language-pragma) enables language extensions.

See [`Language.Haskell.Extension`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/Cabal-2.2.0.1/Language-Haskell-Extension.html#t:KnownExtension) for a list of language extensions understood by GHC, and in particular [`-XScopedTypeVariables`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XScopedTypeVariables) for `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Comment: Well you just killed two birds with one stone there! This definitely fixes the program, but I still have a while to go before I fully understand the type systems in Haskell. While you're here, could you explain to me what the `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` line actually does in general? Also, what else can we write in place of 'ScopedTypeVariables' and what do they do?

Comment: @FloydEverest I added some links.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll have to remember to upvote everything the day I get 15 points - I'm new here from math.Stackexchange. Again, thank you so much for your guidance!